# forget versus grid_forget (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using tkinter for GUI stuff. I noticed that I can use the 'grid' method to align widgets to the appropriate row and column, which references the grid_configure method. However, the forget method, which references grid_forget, does not work in the same way. For example, I think that I should be able to do the following

```
def updateEquationInput(self):     
        self.labelXEQUALS.forget
```

but my label called self.labelXEQUALS isn't removed unless I use grid_forget instead. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is missing `()`.

```
self.labelXEQUALS.forget()
                        ^^
```

As you may know, without `()`, the function/method is not called.

BTW, `forget` is a shortcut for `pack_forget`, not `grid_forget`.

Comment: Oh no no, I just forgot those in here. It still doesn't work if you add those.

Comment: @gnasr, Could you update your question to include minimal example code that show your problem?

Comment: Well, it does show my problem. Actually, do you really need code? It is more of a question of why I can't use .forget() over .grid_forget(), when I could in other code use .grid() over .grid_configure(). To see what I'm talking about, this may help - [link](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/pydoc/Tkinter.Grid.html). Look specifically at 'grid=' and 'forget='. This should help make my question make more sense, but let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: @gnasr, Did you read the part `BTW, ....` in the answer? Try to print `self.labelXEQUALS.forget`, and you will see that it is alias for `pack_forget`, not `grid_forget`.

Comment: @gnasr, If you see the Tkinter source code, you will find `class Widget(BaseWidget, Pack, Place, Grid):` line. Need more explanation?

Comment: @gnasr, If you really want to use `forget` from `Grid`, you can use unbound method `Grid.forget(self.labelXEQUALS)`.

Comment: Yea... I didn't read the BTW. This second explanation helped. But then a followup question would be - why don't I have to do what you just explained for .grid()? And can you explain unbound?

Comment: @gnasr, I recommend you to read about [Method Resolution Order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) regarding why `forget` does not work for `grid`.

Comment: @gnasr, Assuming `s` is `str` object, bound method: `s.lower()`, unbound method: `str.lower(s)`. Search for `python bound unbound` if you need more explanation.